How to stop adding more input values after a certain length has reached?
I'm creating a football lineup creator where the user can select between a keeper, defender, 3 different types of midfielders, and a forward, with each position having a maximum number (this seems to be working well). However, I want the user not to be able to add more players to the lineup when they've added 11 players.
My code as of now is:
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [homeTeam, setHomeTeam] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("homeTeam") === null
        ? {
          squad: {
            gk: null,
            df: [],
            cdm: [],
            cm: [],
            cam: [],
            fw: []
          },
          style: {
            color: `#${state.homeTeamColor}`,
            numberColor: `#${state.homeTeamNumberColor}`,
            nameColor: `#${state.nameColor}`
          }
        }
        : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("homeTeam"))
    );

const addPlayer = () => {
    //const i = 0;
    //while (homeTeam.squad.length < 11 && i < homeTeam.squad.length) {
    setError(null);
    if (playerName === "") {
      setError("Player Name required!");
    }
    //if (homeTeam.squad.length === 11) {
    //  setError("squad is full!");
    //}
    else {
      let playerObj = {
        id: nanoid(),
        number: number,
        name: playerName,
        color:
          playerTeam === "homeTeam"
            ? `#${state.homeTeamColor}`
            : `#${state.awayTeamColor}`,
        numberColor:
          playerTeam === "homeTeam"
            ? `#${state.homeTeamNumberColor}`
            : `#${state.awayTeamNumberColor}`,
        namecolor: `#${state.nameColor}`
      };
      if (playerTeam === "homeTeam") {
        if (playerPosition === "gk") {
          if (homeTeam.squad.gk !== null) {
            setError("goal keeper is full!");
          } else {
            playerObj.onClick = () =>
              playerRemove("homeTeam", "gk", playerObj.id);
            setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
              ...homeTeam,
              squad: { ...homeTeam.squad, gk: playerObj }
            }));
          }
        } else if (playerPosition === "df") {
          if (homeTeam.squad.df.length === 5) {
            setError("defence is full!");
          } else {
            playerObj.onClick = () =>
              playerRemove("homeTeam", "df", playerObj.id);
            setHomeTeam((homeTeam) => ({
              ...homeTeam,
              squad: {
                ...homeTeam.squad,
                df: [...homeTeam.squad.df, playerObj]
              }
            }));
          }
    }
 //CODE IS REPEATED BUT FOR DIFFERENT POSITIONS WHICH I DIDN'T ADD
      }
    }
//}
    setNumber(number + 1); 
  };

The commented code is what I attempted to do. I tried to wrap the whole code in a while loop and that prevented me from adding any players, and when I implemented an if loop with the condition of if (homeTeam.squad.length === 11) {
setError("squad if ull")
}
this adds players without any name being inputted.

you need to use else if, otherwise else only applies to the second condition, not the series of conditions.

Given that you have .onClick = () => - ie a way for the user to remove - then you will want to keep away from loops such as while(squad<11) otherwise your code will get "stuck".  As javascript is single-threaded it won't be able to break out of the loop to handle any events.

@Barmar are you referring to this? I tried doing this but it didn't work
if (playerName === "") {
setError("Player Name required!");
}
else if (homeTeam.squad.length === 11) {
setError("squad is full!");
}
else {
let playerObj = {
........
}

Yes, that's what I'm talking about. I don't know if it's the whole problem, but it's certainly needed.

The problem with the if() statement that you tried, is that homeTeam.squad.length is undefined. To get the number of players on the team, you need to add the length of all the arrays in the squad and add 1 for gk (since it is not an array).
So your commented out if() statement would look like this:
if( 1 + homeTeam.squad.df.length + homeTeam.squad.cdm.length + homeTeam.squad.cm.length + homeTeam.squad.cam.length + homeTeam.squad.fw.length >= 11 ) { 
    setError("squad is full!"); 
}

